# On saving page error : List controllers are not supported for OrderItem

Tags: apex, visualforce, error, exception, standardcontroller

I am trying to do edit for selected OrderItems using StandardSetController, however, when I am saving page, I am getting following error.

> List controllers are not supported for OrderItem.

Followed this Example : [http://www.infallibletechie.com/2014/05/how-to-get-selected-records-from.html]

**VF CODE :**

```
<apex:page standardController="OrderItem" recordSetVar="OrderItem" extensions="OrderItemEditExt">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Mass Edit of OrderItem" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageMessages />
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selected}" var="int">
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!int.Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>      
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class :**

```
public class OrderItemEditExt {
    public OrderItemEditExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
        controller.setPageSize(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kurunve thanks for reply...but this link shows for pagination man ...i need example of edit functionality...